# Task Relationship Issue

Tags: tasks, relationships

I know that task is associated to a custom object by using the "WhatID". 
I need a filter based on if the task exists or not.

For example `parent__c` and `task`:

```
[select id, (select id from tasks) from parent__c ];
```

gives me the correct results.

Now if i need to filter records of `parent__c` which only has tasks how do i do the same ?

I tried:

```
[Select id, (select id from tasks) from parent__c where id in (select whatid from tasks)];
```

and it does not work.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28713/how-to-get-list-of-contacts-which-have-at-least-1-event-in-apex-soql for a 2 step solution

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can simply use who.type, what.type when your are querying on task/event object.

You can get the Who or WHat type in the query no need for a new function and extra round trips.

Query:select id, subject, whoId, who.type,whatId , what.type from task

The who.type will tell you what type of object the whoId is.
The What.type will tell you what object is the Task related to.

So, your query should be select id, subject, whoId, who.type,whatId , what.type from task where what.type = 'Parent__c'

Comment: Varun can you provide more detail?

Comment: This answer appears to rely on the "SOQL Polymorphic Relationships" feature that is presently available as a "Developer Preiew" - see e.g.  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex/index_Left.htm#CSHID=langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm|StartTopic=Content%2FlangCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: As this answer hasn't been accepted it, it's worth noting that the `type` attribute is available in production orgs.